# What is the Ideal value for Worker Processes in Nginx Config?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, configuration, optimization

I have 31GB RAM 8 Core Web Server with current load of 3k per min.

Currently worker_processes parameter in nginx config is 4 which as per my understanding means only 4 cores would be used. But when I see CPU performance I see that all 8 cores have equal load. Why?

[image]

Moreover, making this value 8 would help in my case?

Answer (score 2):

Some other programs uses cpu, like php maybe? Paste all your top output, not only your cpu, but programs too. Turn on visibility of threads too... (H key, if I remember correctly.)

Comment: Let's say there are other processes which are causing this up of CPU consumption. Thus, in such a case is it advisable to add more worker processes (upto max of total number of cores)?

Comment: Probably not. Only case, that you will want that some day nginx could use all of your cpu resources.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_processes):

> The optimal value depends on many factors including (but not limited to) the number of CPU 
>   cores, the **number of hard disk drives** that store data, and load pattern. When one is in doubt, setting it to the number of available CPU cores would be a good start **(the value “auto” will try to autodetect it)**.

So, basically, setting it to the number of CPUs is a good idea. But, if you have disk latency problems, decrease the value.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `worker_processes` is **not** equivalent to the number of CPU cores used. As the name suggests it controls only the number of *individual nginx process instances* that will be running. Any one of these instances will spawn a number of threads to process the incoming requests and these threads will run on all available cores even if you choose to use only a single worker process.

As for why one worker process per CPU is preferable over e.g. only a single one - I don't know. Someone with knowledge of the inner workings of how nginx uses threads would have to shed light on that.

PS. I'm wondering why your server load is so high - we're running a small 2-core server that handles up to 200 req/s with hardly any load at all.